# Shell command line delete files older than n days except the most recent of them

Tags: shell

How to delete files and folders older than `n` days except the most recent of them.

I need to do that in one line within shell.
This works but does not keep the more recent of them :

```
find /base/dir/* -maxdepth 0  -type d -ctime +10 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: *the most recent of them* - sounds unclear

Comment: Please give more clarity with an example having list of files and expected output.

Comment: I have to delete all subfolders older than 10 days, but in case that all subfolders are older than 10 days i must keep the most recent of them.
the goal is to free space but keeping at least one subfolder (the most recent).